aibo developer site に　HTTPリクエストを送ると500エラー（Internal Server Error）となる
aiboデベロッパーサイトのドキュメントにあるaibo Web APIのサンプルコードを実行した際にどのAPIでも500エラーが表示されるようになりました。
期間としては少なくとも2023年の夏ごろまでは同様のコードで問題なくリクエストを送れていましたが，2024年の年始ごろに同じコードでリクエストを送ったところ以下のようなエラーが発生するようになりました。
数日から数か月ほど時間をおいて実行しても改善されませんでした。
どうすれば症状が解消されるようになるでしょうか。
省略）Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

ご指摘があったので実際に使用したコードとエラーを追記します。
Tools.Infoの中身はデバイスIDとアクセストークンの情報を保存しているだけです。
api_nameとargumentsの書き方は間違えていないことを確認済みん，またどのAPIでも同じエラーが出ることも確認済み
import json, sys, time
import urllib.request
import Tools

class ActionAPI:
    def __init__(self, Dvice, LogAddress=None):
        
        Info = Tools.Info(Dvice)
        
        self.DEVICE_ID = Info.deviceID() 
        self.token = Info.token()    
        
    def do_action(self, api_name, arguments, Enqueue=None, TIME_OUT_LIMIT=10):

        if Enqueue == "true":
            Queue = ',"Enqueue":true'
        else:
            Queue = ""

        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token}

        BASE_PATH = 'https://public.api.aibo.com/v1'
        TIME_OUT_LIMIT = TIME_OUT_LIMIT
        post_url = BASE_PATH + '/devices/' + self.DEVICE_ID + '/capabilities/' + api_name + '/execute'
        data = '{"arguments":{' + arguments + Queue + '}}' 

        # POST API
        req = urllib.request.Request(post_url, data.encode(), headers=headers, method='POST')
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as res:
            response = res.read()
        post_result = json.loads(response)
        executionId = post_result["executionId"]

        # Get Result of API execution
        get_result_url = BASE_PATH + '/executions/' + executionId
        TimeOut = 0
        print("start request\n")

        while True:
            req = urllib.request.Request(get_result_url, headers=headers, method='GET')
            with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as res:
                response = res.read()
            get_result = json.loads(response)
            get_status = get_result["status"]

            if get_status == "SUCCEEDED":
                print(get_result)
                break
            elif get_status == "FAILED":
                print(get_result)
                break

            TimeOut += 1
            if TimeOut > TIME_OUT_LIMIT:
                print("Time out")
                break

            time.sleep(1)
        
        return get_result


以下エラー文
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ユーザ名\Desktop\aibo\Move_Tester.py", line 9, in <module>
    act.do_action("play_trick", '"TrickName":"radioExerciseNo1"')
  File "c:\Users\ユーザ名\Desktop\aibo\Action_API.py", line 38, in do_action
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as res:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error


スタックオーバーフローへようこそ。現在の質問内容だと、仮にサンプルをそのまま使ったとしても「どのようなコードを実行した際に発生したか」が分からないため、回答などは付きにくいと思います。まずは、実行した実際のコードを追記してみてはどうでしょうか。また、発生したエラーもなるべく省略しない状態で記載するのが望ましいです。

ただ、HTTPステータス500は文字通りサーバー内部エラーのため、プログラム上の問題とは全く関係ない事情でサーバーがレスポンスしている可能性もあります。そのため、aibo デベロッパープログラムに問い合わせてしまったほうが早く解決するかもしれません。

ご指摘ありがとうございます。指摘通り追記させていただきました。
aiboオーナーサポートに問い合わせたところこちらに質問すれば開発チームが確認してくれるとのことでしたのでこちらで質問させていただきました。

補足：実際 [aibo-developer] タグがついた他の Q&A のように、aibo デベロッパーサポートチームの方が時々見てらっしゃるようです。
