aibo API にリクエストを送るとサーバーエラーが発生する
YouTubeのAPI講座をみながらやっていました。
以下のコードを実行して、aiboの個体名とIDを取得しようとしていたところ、エラーがでました。
curl -X GET \
https://public.api.aibo.com/v1/devices \
-H "Authorization:Bearer ${accessToken}" 

エラーコードはこちらです。
{
    "error": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "message": "Internal server error."
}

サーバーエラーなので、実行したコードには問題ないことはわかりますが、これの解決方法をaiboのオペレーターに問い合わせたところ、ここへ投稿してほしいとのこと。
原因がわかる方いらっしゃいますか？

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/99035/19110 と同根かもしれません（このコメント投稿時点で未解決）。おっしゃるとおり、サーバー側の内部エラーなので aibo 側の問題の可能性が高そうです。

やはりそうですか。大学の研究で使用するため、早めに解決していただけるとありがたいのですけどね…

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/99035/19110 も 2 週間ほど動きがありませんし、見てほしい旨を aibo 側に再度お伝えして良いかもしれませんね……。
